# How did "quantum" come to mean "smallest amount"?

Tags: etymology, terminology

In Latin, it simply means "an amount", which can be of anything and of any size. In modern English, especially in physics, it means the *smallest* amount physically possible, i.e. a physically indivisible amount of something, especially pertaining to energy.

Comment: Have you done any research? Wikipedia has a lot to say in its article https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum

Comment: @StuartF: *Wikipedia* does not answer the OP's actual question. The answer is that Planck did not use *Quantum* for the *smallest* amount physically possible, he used *Elementarquantum*. Around two decades later, physicists started abbreviating *elementary quantum* by *quantum*.

Comment: Wikipedia has a good story for how Planck's paper came to be, and the name of the problem: [The Ultraviolet Catastrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_catastrophe).

Answer (score 6):

If you look at Max Planck's [1900 paper](http://www.ffn.ub.es/luisnavarro/nuevo_maletin/Planck%20%281900%29,%20Distribution%20Law.pdf) (originally in German:  *Zur Theorie des Gesetzes der Energieverteilung im Normalspectrum*) where [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=quantum)
claims he introduced the term, he didn't just use "quantum," he used "elementary quantum" (*Elemantarquantum* in German); that is, the most basic (i.e. smallest) quantity of electric charge.

And Max Planck wasn't even the one who introduced the term in German; I can find quite a few occurrences of *Elementarquantum* in the 1880s and 1890s, and a few before that.

Rather than using "elementary quantum" every time they wanted to refer to one of these things, physicists started abbreviating the term. Already in this [1905 paper of Einstein's](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/andp.19053220607) (for which he got the Nobel Prize), he just uses the words *Energiequant* and *Lichtquant* (*energy quantum* and *light quantum* in English). And at some point in the early 1920s, nearly all physicists stopped using the term "elementary quantum" entirely and called these things  "quanta". You can see this happen in this [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=elementary+quantum+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

Answer (score -1):

The idea of a “small quantity” was introduced at the beginning of the 20th c. by German  physicist Max Planck:

[Quantum:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/quantum)

> The word was introduced in physics directly from Latin by Max Planck, 1900, on the notion of "minimum amount of a quantity which can exist;" reinforced by Einstein, 1905. Quantum theory is from 1912; quantum mechanics, 1922.

(Etymonline)